# How can I display error alert in valid email or password case using Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, uikit

I want to show error notifications when any errors with authentication faced, for example: FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidEmail

how it can possible to realize it in my case?

I do not have any experience with authentication alerts, so decided to ask your help.

here's code of AuthenticationManager:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

final class AuthManager {
    static let shared = AuthManager()
    
    private let auth = Auth.auth()
    
    private init() {}
    
    public var isSignedIn: Bool {
        return auth.currentUser != nil
    }
    
    public func signUp(
        email: String,
        password: String,
        completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void
    ) {
        guard !email.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty,
              !password.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty,
              password.count >= 6 else {
            return
        }
        
        auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            
            // Account Created
            completion(true)
        }
    }
    
    public func signIn(
        email: String,
        password: String,
        completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void
    ) {
        guard !email.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty,
              !password.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty,
              password.count >= 6 else {
            return
        }
        
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            
            completion(true)
        }
    }
    
    public func signOut(
        completion: (Bool) -> Void
    ) {
        do {
            try auth.signOut()
            completion(true)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

as I understand here's should be upgrade code:

```
@objc func didTapSignIn() {
    guard let email = emailField.text, !email.isEmpty, let password = passwordField.text, !password.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    HapticsManager.shared.vibrateForSelection()

    AuthManager.shared.signIn(email: email, password: password) { [weak self] success in
        guard success else {
            return
        }

        // Update subscription status for newly signed in user
        IAPManager.shared.getSubscriptionStatus(completion: nil)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
            let vc = TabBarViewController()
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self?.present(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```